# How to Center a Table in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How do I center-align a table (the table itself, not its content) in PowerPoint? I currently manually adjust the horizontal position to be 1/2 of the Slide's width - table's width. But I'm sure there's a much smarter way.

I'm using PowerPoint 2013.

Answer (score 2):

With the table selected, go to the Layout tab.
In the Arrange group, click Align.
Make sure there's a check next to "Align to Slide"
Then choose Align Center and/or Align Middle to center left/right and/or top/bottom respectively.

Answer (score 1):

By default Power Point will add a table in center of presentation
u can test it yourself, click on an empty area in slide, then insert a table using
the top bar, it shall add it in the center